# Configuring Eclipse And Java JDK

Tags: configuration, eclipse, jdk

I have downloaded a eclipse neon 2 from eclipse site i.e tar file and 
latest java jdk from oracle site i.e tar file and extracted it.
Now eclipse gives error message as its not able to find latest jdk1.8 version.
So how to configure eclipse and where to move that extracted jdk file.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to install a Jave Developement Kit (jdk).  You can install the one from the repository with:

```
$ sudo apt install default-jdk
```

Or the Oracle development kit with:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt install oracle-java8-installer
```

The Oracle installer is a ppa packaged by web8 to make the JDK from http://oracle.com easier to install for a novice.  The Web8 installer will also provide normal upgrade notices when there are updates.